# Symfony 3.2. EntityType not working

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I don't know why this won't work:

```
->add('productSearchType', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'entity.text.product.product_search_number_type',
                'class' => AC\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductSearchType::class,
                'choice_label' => 'designation',
                'expanded' => false,
                'placeholder' => 
'entity.text.product.select_product_search_number_type',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                            ->orderBy('e.designation', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
```

That's the error message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>       Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType::__construct()
>       must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry,
>       none given, called in (...)\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php
>       on line 85 and defined (...)

Comment: Show us how the form is instantiated. You probably did something like `new YourFormType();` instead of getting the form through a form factory service or alike (which is container aware).

Comment: $entity = $this->productService->getVariant($id);

$form = $this->formFactory->create(VariantType::class, $entity, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

Comment: How did you inject the formFactory property then?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your form like this, so the form factory gets access to the container:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->create(VariantType::class, $entity, ['method' => 'POST'])
    ->getForm();
```